# How to do a transaction rollback in corda

Tags: corda

How can I do a transaction rollback in corda. Let's say I've a complex flow which includes 2 flows. I want to rollback the previous transaction if the last one failed how can I do that in corda? Or I need to re-design my complex flow or invalidate the previous state created myself? eg: I've a main flow.in that I created subflow which creates a new state (or updates some state). now suppose for some reason the main flow fails how do I rollback transaction created by my previous subflow?

Comment: Can you give more details on the use case? That will help condition the answer.

Comment: hmm.. lets say I created a state using finality flow(to notarize and vault in respective participants), then it needs to be broadcasted to all nodes that hey new state got created.now if the broadcast fails (for some reason). I don't want that state present to be valid.do I now manually invalidate this state(not sure how) or is there a way to rollback after using finalityFlow.

Answer (score 2):

Once a transaction has been notarised, it is final and cannot be rolled back. However, depending on how the transaction's contracts are written, it may be possible to consume the newly created state to create the old state again.

Regarding your comment, the broadcast cannot "fail" in Corda unless one of the nodes permanently leaves the network. ACKs are used to ensure messages between nodes are always received.

Comment: I think I'll have to come up with a better scenario. but thanks for clarifying. Once Notarized cannot be rolled back. In real life scenario there will certainly be a case where we would want to rollback.... for instance if I've a flow that updates a state(suppose sets status of state to processed) and creates another state response. Since I should be calling finality flow only once I need to create 2 seperate txbuilders in the same flow for update and create and get their signedTranscation ? now once I have that I call FinalityFlow to notarize them independently ? is this the way to go?

Comment: if that's the way I think Finality Flow should accept a list of signed Transaction as well.